# PowerBi Row level security for multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, row-level-security

Iam having a difficulty in implementing Dynamic row level security for below given scenario. I have two tables ( User Master and Main data table). Once the user logs in code should compare the columns in user master table ( Branch code, Product code, Access level,Vehicle type) and display the data in main table which is associated with the logged in user. Also if the logged in user access level is M, Then no filtering should occur and he should be able to view the entire data. Request you all to help

I tried many combinations like calculatetable, filter, summarize but all are returning different errors

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.